# CountIFs Beyond

Tags: worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to compile a summary sheet that takes the Employee Name from Row 5, summarizes how many red (2) or yellow (1) are in any given month.

[image]

I have figured out the COUNTIF for it as a whole, but I cannot figure out how to do the sum of 2's for any specific employee.  Been at it for two days.  None of my logical formulas seem to look at the employee name and count how many red.

[image]

Any help (non SQL) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit you question and post your formula. We cannot see your row numbers, so we don't know what you mean with row 5. Also, I don't understand how you explicitly exclude SQL. We're looking at a spreadsheet here, so why would you reference and exclude SQL? Might as well exclude C#, Java, Javascript, whatever??

Comment: if you get rid of the merged cells and put a real date into each of the cells in the row with dates, and if you have a corresponding date value in the output table, you can use Sumproduct() to calculate across a matrix like this.